# Ngrx pattern for dispatching action and checking if backend call was successful

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

What is the correct way for dispatching an action which calls an endpoint to perform an update on backend?

Current suggestion is to have an action and an action_success and action_fail for each action. As an example if we want to edit a course, we will dispatch an action called course_update, in the effect for this action an endpoint is called, if the result of the backend is successful, we dispatch course_update_success and if not course_update_fail is dispatched.

This results in 3 action for each call. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I have not found a better way for API calls. Always three actions to set loading, data, or error.

Comment: This is an ngrx's flow. Also, you could simply call some alert if there is no hard logic to do for views. And to mention - you don't need to always use ngrx(from creators of ngrx) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t3jx0EC-Y3c

Comment: Thanks for good question. Did you find solution?

Comment: @johannesMatevosyan I think switching to react and react query solved most of my issues.